# Camel Route for orchestrating services

Tags: asynchronous, spring-boot, apache-camel, messaging, rx-java

I have a Spring Boot based micro service (PolicyService) which is protected using Spring Security OAuth2 as a resource component.

So, a check , if the user is authenticated or not is done by validating the token received in the request using Authorization Server component.

Also, internally, within the service I check for Current User's Roles and ACE for requested object (for Update , Delete and Read operations ) to
determine if the current user has required permissions for executing target operation or not. I use Spring Security method level annotations for Role check and a custom ACL Service for domain object level permissions.

Once I determine, that the user is authenticated and also has the required authorizations for the requested operation  and/or object,
a policy is created in the database.

Also, I call another operation in ACL Service from Policy Service to add  ACE (access control entry) for the created object and the User.

If at any point there is a failure, I throw an exception as "access denied."

I now want to orchestrate this service using a Composite service based on Apache Camel.

I want to know if it it is better to separate out the steps for checking for authorizations using ACL Service 
and also adding a ACL Entry once the policy is created , as separate steps in Apache camel.

As of now, they are all consumed by the Policy Service.

Also, I now have a requirement to do a validation for the Policy being created which is currently time consuming, so I want to use messaging by sending an event to a Queue which would be monitored by a service which validates and updates the database and sends a mail accordingly based on the outcome of the validation.

I want to know if it is better to extract these different functionalities as individual steps in a Camel Route as below or use them within the Policy Service.

If I extract the Role Check to the Composite Service,  that means I need to add Spring Security to the Spring Boot based Apache Camel Composite Service to secure the service.

I currently do ACL permission check (not for Create but for other operations ) using Spring Security method level annotations and custom ACL Service. I believe I may have to redo the logic in a different way within the Camel Service now.

Also, which would be a better way to invoke the Policy Validation Service using asynchronous, messaging or by raising custom events using event-sourcing.

Also, is there any support in Apache Camel for raising custom events using event-sourcing and asynchronous service invocation

I currently have a route designed as below in Camel.

```
<route id="createPolicy">
        <from uri="direct:createPolicy"/> 

            <!-- Check if User has the Role(s) required for this operation , handled internally by Policy Service using Spring Security-->
            <bean ref="aclClientBean" method="checkRoleForCreatePolicy(${body})"/> 

            <!-- Create a Policy using Policy Service -->
            <bean ref="policyClientBean" method="createPolicy(${body})"/>

            <!-- Add ACE for Policy Instance and Current User using ACL Service , handled internally by Policy Service using ACL Service-->
            <bean ref="aclClientBean" method="addACLForPolicy(${body})"/>

            <!--Validating the Policy Details-->

            <!-- Option 1:Send a message to a configured Policy Validation Queue which is monitored by Policy Validation Service -->
            <!-- Option 2:Send a event that Policy is created, whoever interested on Policy Creation Event will subscribe to the event
            and act accordingly when notified -->
            <!-- Option 3:Asynchronously invoke the Policy Validation Service and validate the passed details -->

            <bean ref="policyValidationClientBean" method="validatePolicyDetails(${body})"/>


         <onException>
                <exception>com.company.application.exception.AuthException</exception>
                <handled>
                        <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <to uri="direct:authException"/>
        </onException>

        <onException>
                <exception>com.company.application.exception.APPException</exception>
                <handled>
                        <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <to uri="direct:appException"/>
        </onException>
</route>

 <route id="authException">
    <from uri="direct:authException"/>
    <log message="Access Denied."/>
    <bean ref="policyOrchestratorClientBean" method="handleFailure('Access Denied.')"/>
</route>


<route id="appException">
    <from uri="direct:appException"/>
    <log message="Exception invoking  Service"/>
    <bean ref="policyOrchestratorClientBean" method="handleFailure('Exception invoking  Service')"/>
</route>
```